# imagick-3.4.4 installation throws error on make: grep: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libfreetype.la: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick, bitnami, webp

I'm running a bitnami wordpress stack and I'm trying to figure out how to enable webp support for GD or imagick. After trying for a while and using different approaches I found online I have to ask for help here:

**GD is enabled and installed, however webp support ist boolean false.**

I read that installing the latest version of imagick-3.4.4 should do the trick, however when doing so.

When doing this:

```
cd /tmp/webp
curl -LO https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.4.tgz
tar xvzf imagick-3.4.4.tgz
cd imagick-3.4.4
phpize
./configure --with-imagick=/opt/bitnami/common --prefix=/opt/bitnami/common
make
sudo make install
```

After make I get the following error:

```
> grep: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libfreetype.la: No such file or
> directory /bin/sed: can't read /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libfreetype.la:
> No such file or directory libtool: link:
> `/opt/bitnami/common/lib/libfreetype.la' is not a valid libtool
> archive Makefile:215: recipe for target 'imagick.la' failed make: ***
> [imagick.la] Error 1
```

Any idea what I have to do here in order to be able to install imagick correctly?